# Que signifie « mais peine à [faire quelche chose] » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> De fait, la presse britannique couvre largement la présidentielle
>   française, [**mais peine à**](http://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2017/04/24/les-britanniques-incredules-devant-le-succes-du-pro-europeen-macron_5116344_4854003.html) y voir autre chose que l’irrésistible
>   ascension de Mme Le Pen. Ainsi, la chef du Front national trône-t-elle
>   rayonnante à la « une » du *Times* de lundi, qui titre sur *«
>   l’humiliation des élites françaises »*. Quant au très europhobe
>   *Telegraph*, il estime que l’élection de M. Macron *« serait une mauvaise nouvelle pour la Grande-Bretagne »*.

Je veux vous dire d’abord que je sais ce que **à peine** signifie en français : *hardly*. Mais je ne sais pas ce que l'inversion (**peine à**) de cette expression consacrée par les dictionnaires pourrait signifier.

De plus, je ne peux pas comprendre ce que **mais + peine à + faire quelque chose** (***mais peine à [faire quelque chose]***) signifie, et comment je pourrais la traduire en anglais. Je l'ai vue dans beaucoup de contextes, donc je crois que cette expression est une expression fixe, mais, malgré tout cela, je n'ai pu la trouver dans aucun dictionnaire dans lequel je l'ai trouvée.

Si elle est vraiment une expression idiomatique de la langue française, pourquoi n'est-elle dans aucun dictionnaire en tant qu'expression idiomatique ?

Comment: en anglais "but struggles to see anything other than"

Comment: This was a misreading of à peine and peiner.

Comment: You got some good answers already. Just wanna add that a French equivalent to the classic English sarcasm _‘Here’s Feelew working hard... um... hardly working I mean’_ could be _‘Tiens! Voici Feelew qui peine au travail... euh... qui travaille à peine, je veux dire’._

Answer (score 5):

Il s'agit ici du verbe ***peiner (à)*** qui est veut dire *avoir de la peine (à)* / *du mal (à)* / *des difficultés à* / *faire quelque chose*. Autrement dit la phrase veut dire que la presse britannique a du mal / des difficultés à voir dans la présidentielle française autre chose que l’irrésistible ascension de Mme Le Pen.

D'autres exemples d'emploi :

> Je peine à marcher à cause de mon entorse.
>
> Mon fils peine toujours à faire ses exercices de maths.

La différence entre *peiner à* et *avoir du mal à* est essentiellement stylistique : *peiner à* est d'un niveau de langue plus élevé.

*Peiner* (transitif et construit sans la préposition *à*) peut aussi avoir un autre sens : faire de la peine à quelqu'un, chagriner :

> Cette nouvelle l'a beaucoup peiné.

Il n'y a pas de rapport avec la locution adverbiale *à peine* qui effectivement peut se traduire par *hardly* en anglais.

Comment: C'est tout clair : donc je dois élargir de manière exponentielle mon vocabulaire français...

Comment: Merci pour vos compliments ! Mais je suis par tempérament complètement perfectionniste.

Comment: Je me demande si  cet auteur a choisi cette tournure plus élevée pour la même raison que le mot «trump» (surtout en verbe) se trouvait/se trouve souvent comme jeu de mots dans les articles au sujet de candidat et hélas, maintenant Président Trump.  En tout cas, personnellement,  j’espère bien qu’en 2 semaines il n’y aura plus besoin de parler à ce niveau plus élevé pour décrire le mal qu’on aura.

Comment: @PapaPoule Le style du monde est rarement familier, même si on y trouve plus de fautes que naguère.  Mais il n'y a pas de jeux de mot ici, comme on peut en rencontrer avec Trump. Des Français peuvent sentir une pointe d'ironie dans ce passage...  à l'égard des britanniques.

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe **peiner** signifie "avoir du mal/des difficultés". Il est distinct de l'expression **à peine**, bien que les deux aient à même étymologie (du latin *poena, poenae*, signifiant punition, ou châtiment).

La raison pour laquelle ce n'est pas présent en tant expression idiomatique et donc que *peine à* est simplement la conjugaison du verbe *peiner*.

Quand quelqu'un *peine à [X]*, il *a du mal à [X]*. En anglais, on le traduira généralement par **struggle to [X]**.

Answer (score 0):

Peine is related to 'pain' in English, as in 'suffering'.  It can become more extreme 'punishment' as in 'peine de mort'. 
Peiner a faire quelque chose veut dire avoir du mal a le faire.  A peine however does mean hardly, almost - I guess similar to "you'd be hard-pressed to see a difference"?
Note that 'a peine' is still used commonly, while 'peiner a' is fast fading into literary history.